# What's the feed RSS URL for bountied questions coupled with a specific tag?

Tags: support, bounties, feed

The feed RSS URL for a tag in stackoverflow is this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=TAGNAME
```

Is there a way to have only the bountied question for that tag?

Thank you

Comment: Can you try `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=TAGNAME&sort=featured`

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=tag&sort=featured

Comment: You have added only sorting, why this should filter bountied questions?

Comment: @aborruso That's also how the tag websites shows the bountied questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=latex&sort=featured

Comment: @aborruso And did it work?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find the feed for bountied question of a certain tag is to start from their list on the website, e.g.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=latex&sort=featured
```

From there you can either make an educated guess or use a feed indicator like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/feed-indicator/ to get the corresponding news feed for the site, e.g.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=latex&sort=featured
```

(replace `latex` with whatever tag you are interested in)